# How to customise the Recommended Programs list when choosing what to open a file with?

Tags: windows-vista, file-association

How can I change what applications are listed in the Recommended Programs list below? I checked the various options in `Control Panel > Default Programs`, but none appear to allow me to affect this specific list.

I'm asking because the recommended programs appear in the `Open With...` context menu in Windows Explorer and it's getting pretty long (and in this case, contains completely random items like Steam. Why would I want to open a .png file in Steam?!)

[image: Open With dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Read this post about how to do it

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/05/how-to-unassociate-remove-or-delete-programs-from-open-with-or-recommended-programs-list/

It should help with what you need to be done.

Comment: Oof, registry editing? In 6 different places? I guess technically it solves my problem, but surely someone's made a program or something that GUIs this up for me?

Comment: I'll add this to the list of software to develop :) But atm just take your time on the registry, it's not soo bad

Comment: I took all the steps and all programs were removed from this list except for Java(TM) Web Start Launcher which was the application I wanted to remove. Is there any possibility to also remove this one? When I just reassign javaws.exe it seems that the old (non-working) entry is used.

Comment: I solved it, uninstalling Java and rebooting removes also this entry.

Answer (score 0):

The steps described in [in this Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258860) may help.

> **WARNING:** If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause serious
>   problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system.
>   Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can solve problems that result
>   from using Registry Editor incorrectly. Use Registry Editor at your
>   own risk.
>
> The programs on the **Open With** list for each file type are independent
>   of that file's registered program(s). To remove items from this list,
>   locate the following registry key within `regedit`
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.extension\OpenWithList`
>
> where extension is the file extension for the file type whose **Open
>   With** list you want to modify. Delete the value in this key that
>   represents the program to be removed from the **Open With** list.
>
> NOTE: The above registry key
>   is one path, it has been wrapped for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)** to customize the 'Open with...' list.

Open the app, and go to `File Type Settings`, then click this link:

[image: Change Open With Programs]

Select the file extension you're trying to change, `.png` in this case, then click next:

[image: Add or remove Open With programs]

From that screen you can add/remove what shows up on that file type's 'Open with...' list.

Comment: This looks like Windows 7, not Windows Vista?