# How to add Xodo to Open With menu for PDFs

Tags: windows-8.1

How do I add Xodo (a PDF reader) to the Open With menu for PDFs?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/184459/how-to-customise-the-recommended-programs-list-when-choosing-what-to-open-a-file/416140#416140 check this, i could'nt flag as duplicate it havent an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This works in Windows 7, and in my limited experience with Windows 8.1, this will work there as well.*

1. Find a PDF file somewhere, and right-click it.
2. Choose `Properties`.
3. Click `Change` next to the `Open With` information.
4. Click `Browse`.
5. Select the program you want to use (likely in `C:\Program Files\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.
6. Now, **Uncheck** the box that says 'Always use the selected program...'. If you do not uncheck that box, the program you are selecting will not only be in the Open With menu, but also be chosen as the *default* program to open that type of file. If this is what you want, leave the box checked.
7. Now click `OK`
8. Now, whenever you right-click a PDF file, in the Open With menu, will be the program you selected!